Does lead nullify Superman's other senses?
One of Superman's famous weaknesses is his inability to see through lead. Although I'm not sure why that's the case from a physiological perspective (I'm sure that could be a separate question), it did lead me to wonder if lead would nullify his other senses. Superman is commonly depicted as having super-hearing, less commonly as having super-smelling, and perhaps never as having super-tasting (I'm not sure how that would manifest itself anyway). Would those heightened senses be impacted if lead were involved? If, for example, there were an audibly ticking time bomb in a lead chest, would Superman be able to hear it?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80849/x-ray-vision-of-superman-is-lead-the-only-element-stopping-the-ability  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/can-superman-kill-people-with-his-x-ray-vision

I don't know if it's technically consistent with canon - but x-ray vision ought to be passive detection like TNG Geordi LaForge being able to see the full EM spectrum.  The x-ray images we are used to is from shooting an X-ray THROUGH an object to a detector behind the object.  Being able to see ultra faint radioactive decay x-rays emitted from bones for example seems better to me than the radar style bounce x-rays off the subject he's looking at and get a reflection to "see".   In this model lead isn't affecting him, just blocking too much natural x-rays making it too faint even for him.

Super-tasting would detect traces of poisons in food. Can be useful on planets with poorly documented lifeforms.

@lucasbachmann It looks like Superman can choose on which spectrum his eyes work (visible light, or x-ray). It's what he did in DCeased: he "switched" to x-ray spectrum to avoid seeing any kind of digital screen.

There's a comic (I don't remember which one) which has a character asking "How'd you find me?  This closet was lead-lined." and Superman replies "I smelled you out.  I had that suitcase treated with ..."

In The Dark Knight Returns, Batman sets a trap for Superman that is triggered by the x-rays from his vision. I also remember (not sure if this was DKR or another comic) someone mentioning that the intensity of x-rays he uses is low enough that it doesn't increase cancer risk. So in at least one canon Superman's x-ray vision works by emitting actual x-rays, which would explain lead blocking it but not other senses.

Superman #315 (1977) and Superboy #107 seem pretty definitive on this. Lead only blocks his super-vision, not his other super-senses. In both cases his super-hearing works just fine through solid lead.



That all being said, Superman is apparently incapable of hearing his son Jon in Superman: Lois and Clark - Doom Rising when he's locked into a box with foot-thick lead walls.
It's not especially clear whether it's that the walls are lead, or merely very thick that's the problem, but it's evident that he can't hear the yelling through them.

Note that this is an Elseworlds kinda deal, so the usual rules might not apply here.

Makes sense. Superman isn't hard science fiction and complete scientific accuracy isn't expected - but Superman has "X-ray vision" and it's common knowledge that lead can block X-rays.

@Robyn Trivia: in the Justice League animated series, Clark's adoptive parents lined the Christmas gifts with lead to prevent him from peaking into them, which is why he still believes Santa is the one putting the gifts under the Christmas tree..

Dense and thick materials dampen sound, so his super-hearing should not work.  Of course X-rays also shoot out of his eyes, so better not to think too hard.

@RonJohn sound travels easier through denser materials. You need atoms to vibrate to transfer sound and the closer the atoms are, the easier is to make others vibrate. If you have no atoms (vacuum) you don't have sound. Compare air vs water. If you've ever made a "phone" from two cups connected by string, you've experienced first hand how sound is transmitted easier through a denser material. If not, you surely know of this technique. Sound dampening is a different property of materials than their density.

@VLAZ I don't know much about physics, but I was told one way of dampening sound beside creating a vacuum and fake ceiling is to use more dense material, because the heavier wall is less likely to vibrate and transmit the sound wave. Air vs water is a good example: if I scream at the bottom of the swimming pool, chances are you will only hear the bubbles popping at the surface of water (water is 1000 times more dense than air).

@Clockwork whales communicate over vast distances in water. Way more than a shout in air carries. And we can listen in on a lot of things via sonar. Water is a good sound transmitter. If you've lived in a block of flats with heating pipes, then you would be extremely well aware of how far banging on the radiator carries. Not even hammering with all your might but bumping it with moderate force will alert everybody on the same pipe. Metal tends to be denser than water.

@VLAZ I think there's a difference between being inside the material and using it as a dampener.

@VLAZ "sound travels easier through denser materials."  I had to Google before making that comment.  It's why I specifically used the phrase "Dense and thick".  https://www.phelpsgaskets.com/blog/material-for-sound-proofing-and-sound-dampening "If the material's density is too low, the sound waves are transmitted through. If the density is too high, the waves get reflected off the material's surface."

Similarly to Valorum's answer, in episode My Girl from Superman: The animated Series, Lana Lang was captured by one of Luthor's goons because although she was dating Lex Luthor, she was discreetly passing information to Superman.
The last information she gave him was a false one which was meant to divert Superman's attention to Central City (aka. away from Metropolis), whilst she was about to be killed in a lead factory, which blocked Superman's x-ray vision, preventing him to see where Lana was actually held hostage.
However, to the goon's dismay, Superman bursts in and announces that although he cannot see through lead, his hearing works well enough. I couldn't find any excerpt on Youtube though, so all I can share is a transcript:

Lana: Let me go, you maniac! Help! Help!
Mr. Ealan: That won't do you any good, Ms. Lang. Nobody's here. The factory is fully automated because of the lead field. In fact, there's so much lead residue on the walls, I doubt Superman could see through them, even if he weren't in Central City.
Superman (after crashing through the roof): You're right, Ealan, I couldn't see you. But my hearing's pretty good.

